# CS:GO kick/ban in competitive match making

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

I was kicked from a competitive match making earlier today right after the game ended, so I was wondering if it counted as a loss because I got kicked or if it just counted as a win because the game ended already?

Comment: You can't get kicked after the game ended. Round 13 is the last round where you can kick someone out.

Comment: Nope, you can now even kick on 15:x round.

Comment: @Conreuss Please specify: Do you want to know if you can lose your rank because of this or do you really want to know if it just affects your win/lose ratio? Then I can answer you on both. :)

Comment: @Noneofyourbusiness actually they changed it you can get at the end of the game when the score shows up, thats what happened to me

Answer (score 1):

If you are kicked from a game, it counts as a loss on your rank, regardless of whether your team won or not.

Comment: Do you have a source for that ? After a quick source I didn't find any official reference. Only the same question, and people answering without providing any source.

Answer (score 1):

Being kicked from a game does, in fact, count as a loss regardless of whether or not your team won. [Here](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=3257959) is a Steam Forum thread by someone who shows disdain regarding this condition along with others expressing their views on the kick process in general.